# Rest assured is giving 502 in return

Tags: api, testing, automation, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have simple get API

```
https://abc.xyz.co/index.php?route=efg/api/jkl&key=8454jdgdkjf948754&source=android&user_id=44
```

when i hit in browser I receive 200 OK but when i send request using rest assured it gives 502 in return.
Below is the code I am using

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://abc.xyz.co/";
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
Response response = request.queryParam("route", "efg/api/jkl").
                queryParam("key","8454jdgdkjf948754").
                queryParam("source","android").
                queryParam("user_id","44").get("/index.php");
System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
```

Someone please look into this

Note: URL shared is dummy URL but format is same as per my project

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in base url and endpoint url:

- `"https://abc.xyz.co/"`
- `"/index.php"`

which gives together `"https://abc.xyz.co//index.php"`, so one slash character "/" is redundant. Try to remove it either for base url or endpoint url and it should work.

Comment: Hi Villa_7,  I did same thing as u said but it didn't work even if I am hitting URL having double slash in it it is giving me 200 Okay. I tested on other APIs it work fine in rest assured but i dot know why it is not working for it . Can u please suggest something else or some other piece of code

Comment: API is fine because it is giving me 200 when hit in browser

Comment: So this is basically an URL of website which you're trying to hit via API?
If so, this won't work, because API has its own address which differs with website address. Try to observe it in 'Network' tab in Devtools

Comment: Hi Villa_7, No, this is not a URL this is get API which gives JSON response in return. Can u please share your telegram id or skype id where I can connect to u

Comment: @Iamarjun you can find my skype id at the following url - https://pastebin.com/bj0ufwwC (link will be expired in 24h after this comment)